# Define an __invoke magic method on JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
function Queue() {
}

var q = new Queue();
```

Is it possible to have `q` call a method when invoked like a function? Calling `q()` just gives an error:

> TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: `q()` doesn't call anything, not even the constructor. If you are asking whether you can make arbitrary objects callable, the answer is no. Technically it should be possible, since functions are just objects with a special internal `[[Call]]` property, but the spec doesn't allow to modify it in user code.

Comment: @FelixKling: I'm aware... it gives a TypeError as shown in the comment. Jack's answer seems to work, so how isn't this possible?

Comment: @Mark but then `new Queue instanceof Queue == false`

Comment: Well, that solution explicitly returns a function. Of course you can call functions. I said you cannot make *arbitrary* objects callable. FWIW, you might be able to use [function proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies) in the next version of ECMAScript.

Comment: @elclanrs: Ahh...poop. I want to access `this` inside of the invoked function.

Comment: I think you should just provide a more complete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah I see. Since functions are just objects as well, the only way to "simulate" a callable object is by actually creating a function. You can also directly assign any properties to it (since it's an object). The only thing you can't do is make it inherit from another object. But if that's not necessary in your use case, then using a function is the solution to your problem.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah... I really messed this up. I don't need `this` at all, I can just declare `queue` as a local variable and it will be available in the nested functions.

Comment: Then you don't even have to use `new Queue()`, you could just call `Queue()`. Anyways, at least you found a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach to making your code work is to return a function from the constructor:

```
function Queue()
{
    return function() {
        alert('Hello world');
    };
}
```

This works, because returning an object from a constructor will "replace" what otherwise would be an instance of `Queue`. Basically, this approach allows you to return a "public interface" and the instance of `Queue` can be closed over:

```
function Queue()
{
    var self = this; // instance of Queue

    return function() {
        // use 'self'
        alert('Hello world');
    };
}
```

But what you're returning from the constructor is now **no longer a Queue instance**, so a true `__invoke()` like  PHP is not possible.

#### Update

The use-case (before it was deleted) was this:

```
function Queue() {
    var q = [];

    return function(f) {
        q.push(f);

        return function(status) {
            if(q.length > 0) {
                return q.shift()();
            }
        }
    };
}

var q = Queue(),
a = q(function() { console.log('a'); }),
b = q(function() { console.log('b'); });

b(); a(); // prints 'a' and then 'b'
```

Comment: No, your first answer was exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Once we have [proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies), we can handle calls to non existing properties (or rather *access* to non-existing properties). But I guess it's a loooong way until we get there.

Comment: @FelixKling How long would you say? Few years? Never? :)

Comment: Lets talk about it again in 2020 ;)

Comment: @Mark I've tried to keep up with the question .. hope it still makes sense now :)

Comment: @Jack: Makes sense now, but returning a function from a "constructor" is counter-intuitive. Any caller would expect an object instance, not a function, so it's best to just do it like in your "Update" section where we don't use `new` at all. Add a tidbit to say "No, you can't define a method such that an object can be invoked (at least not yet)" and I'll accept this!

Comment: @Mark Done. The note was already there, but I've made it bold :)

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, javascript does this by default. If you create a variable that's an object, if you attempt to call it, it will already throw an exception that says the object isn't a function.

Second of all, if you're in any way looking for php-like magic methods, look no further than `Proxy`.

```
var x = new Proxy({},{get(target,name) {
  return "Its hilarious you think I have "+name
}})

console.log(x.hair) // logs: "Its hilarious you think I have hair"
```

Check out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Works in chrome, firefox, and node.js. Downsides: doesn't work in IE yet - freakin IE. Soon.

Comment: Neat. Didn't know about this Proxy object.